# How to display youtube playlist wordpress metabox

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am using Youtube Playlist Thumbs

```
$playlist = playlist_get_meta( 'playlit_songs' );

<?php echo wpautop($playlist); ?>
```

It only displays plugin shortcode. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Im using Youtube Playlist Thumbs plugin. i got created metabox for post and with plugin im trying to display playlist but it only show plugin shortcode. <?php echo wpautop($playlist); ?>

Comment: The variable $playlist contains the shortcode to display the playlist, am I correct? If so, you can evaluate the shortcode by using: `<?php echo do_shortcode($playlist); ?>`